# How to get socket.io expo app production ready when it points to localhost:3000

Tags: socket.io, expo

I have an expo app with a node.js backend which I am hosting on the digitalocean app platform. I'm using socket.io for websockets, and right now the cors url in my server points to localhost:3000.

I want to submit my expo app to the app store, and it's my first time deploying a mobile app. I'm assuming I can't keep using localhost:3000. Do I need to use some cloud service to host my frontend and get a url, similar to how I used digitalocean for the server?

Answer (score 0):

I changed origin to `origin: "*",` and it works, going to try submitting it. I'm not accepting this as the correct answer though, because I don't know if it's correct. But leaving it here in case it helps anyone else, or in case anyone has constructive feedback for me.